# MongoDb serialize generic types (classes)

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

What is the general advice on serializing something like this in MongoDb

```
    public class BaseCategorization<T> where T : BaseCategory
    {
        public BaseCategorization()
        {
            Type = typeof(T).Name;
        }

        public BaseCategorization(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
            Type = typeof(T).Name;
        }

...
}
```

I use it like this:

```
_documentsProvider.Save<BaseCategorization<ProductCategory>>(newProductCategorization);
```

where `ProductCategory : BaseCategory` and `BaseCategory` is `abstract`.

The above seems to work, only problem is the strange name of the resulting collection, `BaseCategorization'1`, and the fact that I don't know whether this design is fine by MongoDb terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can store all of your documents in one collection, however it is probably easier and cleaner in the long run to only store one type in a collection (from a C# perspective). You can do this by creating a class with an Extension Method on MongoDatabase.

```
public static class MyDatabase
{
    public static MongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(this MongoDatabase db)
    {
        var name = typeof(T).Name;
        return db.GetCollection<T>(name);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call GetCollection with your type on it and the name will be hidden from your general code. You can also create something like this to abstract things a little bit further:

```
public class MyDatabase
{
    private MongoDatabase _db;

    public MyDatabase(MongoDatabase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public MongoCollection<object> Objects
    {
        get
        {
            return _db.GetCollection<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can just do

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("MyDb");
var myDb = new MyDatabase(db);
myDb.Objects.Find();
```

This `Find` will map to execute against the `Objects` collection, simply replace `<object>` with your type and give the collection a name.