# C# mongodb serialize an object with a generic property

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, serialization

I have a class with one property of generic type,

```
public class FactorRecord<T>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FactorName { get; set; }
    public T FactorValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

From this question [MongoDb serialize generic types (classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616789/mongodb-serialize-generic-types-classes), I know how to serialize a generic object, but I am not sure how to serialize in my case in which only one property is of generic type.

Comment: Since I'm irritatingly not allowed to post a comment saying "What have you tried?" I will ask you to explain any problems you've encountered in your quest to serialize instances of this class.

Comment: @phoog, well, i dont think i can make a compilable code out of this. So right now I am going with replacing T with actual types like double and string, and have two class like NumericFactorRecord and TextFactorRecord.